# 3D-Touch Home Screen Quick Action do not work in cold start

Tags: ios, swift

(iOS 13)

It is worked when app from suspend to active in hot start.
ShortcutItem will be caught in following method:

```
func windowScene(_ windowScene: UIWindowScene, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)
```

But when I force close and restart the app, then 3D-Touch Home Screen Quick Action does not work.

I can not catch the shortcutItem user tapped in following method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool
```

When I try to log the shortcutItem in launchOptions, it's nil.

Please tell me where is wrong?

Comment: Do you have any crash logs? if so what do they say?

Comment: It doesn't crash, it will go directly to main interface instead of the interface you want to go in quick action.

Comment: You're not referencing the View Controller correctly then.